# How to keep single checkableBehavior mode in drawer menu for NavigationView when we add section?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design

I try to implement a drawer with new component of material design : [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html).

It's work very well. When I select an item changes its color change well with `android:checkableBehavior="single"`.

```
<group
    android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_home"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/home"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_favourite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/favourite"/>
    ...

    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/settings"/>

</group>
```

The problem come when I try to use section in drawer. It's this case, I can't use `android:checkableBehavior="single"` and I lost the color change in the selection of an item.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/section"
    android:title="@string/section_title">

    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_favourite"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/favourite"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_downloaded"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_file_download_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/downloaded"/>
    </menu>

</item>
```

Comment: I reported this issue to google developer last week. It was assigned and will be released in the next update. So you have only to wait the update of support repositories

Comment: Is there a bug id so we can track this?

Comment: Can you give the bug id @Fondesa

Answer (score 10):

try this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_home"
            android:checked="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/home"/>

       <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_favourite"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/favourite"/>
       ...

       <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/settings"/>
       <item
            android:id="@+id/section"
            android:title="@string/section_title">

            <menu>
                <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/drawer_favourite"
                        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
                        android:title="@string/favourite"/>

                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/drawer_downloaded"
                        android:icon="@drawable/ic_file_download_black_24dp"
                        android:title="@string/downloaded"/>
                </group>
            </menu>

       </item>

    </group>
</menu>
```

you can check this solution for details..
[I am unable to set a submenu item as checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30922012/i-am-unable-to-set-a-submenu-item-as-checked)

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround until the bug reported by Fondesa is fixed you can use this:

**Menu Definition**

```
<item android:checkable="true" ...>
```

**Styling**

```
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/error_color"/>
```

This will properly highly the menu item when selected.

Note that this will not address the requirement:

```
android:checkableBehavior="single"
```

You will have to handle that manually.