# issue to remove NavigationView menu item selected color?

Tags: android, android-navigationview

Hi all i am facing one strange issue. I added `Navigation View` in my `Activity` and by default every time when i start the App the first navigation item selected with some background color.

I want to remove this feature.

### My gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
}
```

### Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
  }
}
```

### Menu XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Import" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />
</group>
```

### Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

### SnapShot::

[image]

Any hint how to remove this type of features?

Comment: Can you post your Activity code?

Comment: @PratikButani ya off course wait

Comment: are you using, for first item, android:checked="true"

Comment: this is you selected android:checkableBehavior="single" on group, if needed remove group from menu and put items directly inside menu tag

Comment: @virendrao If i remove it still happened bro.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045008/how-to-keep-single-checkablebehavior-mode-in-drawer-menu-for-navigationview-when may get some clue

Comment: Just a hint - `findViewById` is an expensive method in android. It is recommended to only call it once and make the object global in your class. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's working now. I just change `appcompat` and `design` **libs** with latest one.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

Answer (score 33):

Just return false, it will be in unchecked state and vice versa

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_camera:

                break;
            case R.id.nav_gallery:

                break;
            case R.id.nav_slideshow:

                break;
            case R.id.nav_manage:

                break;
        }
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: If you set return false; then it will be in unchecked state and vice versa.

Answer (score 14):

```
return false;
```

In the end of `public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)`

does the job

Answer (score 9):

You can completely control item background color, just change [`itemBackground`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#attr_NavigationView_itemBackground) attribute of `NavigationView`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent" />
```

You can use `ColorStateList` as well to set different background for checked state and unchecked state.

Answer (score 6):

Anywhere in your code or any fragment are you using like

```
navigationview.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_camera).setChecked(true);
```

than its possible otherwise you can check it in updated Support library as in v23 its working fine

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

return false; 
If you set return false; then it will be in unchecked state and vice versa